# How to remove extra swap partitions at Ubuntu install menu?

Tags: 11.10

I found my computer to have 11 swap partitions originated by previous fresh installs. I want to delete them, and I don't mind doing a fresh install again. The problem is that I am a newbie and I don't know how to edit partitions to delete swaps in the Ubuntu 11.10 install menu. Where do I have to clic? Delet? Change?

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu, there will be a menu right after the "Install Ubuntu" button is clicked (not the "Try Ubuntu" button). It asks you to choose between these options: Erase all Operating systems and Install, Install Ubuntu side by side, Upgrade Ubuntu, and choose something else. Select the "Choose something else option". You will then continue to a hard drive reformatting menu. This menu is very powerful! Once you make changes it can become permanent and data loss can/will occur. If you do make an mistake, click the back button. This should restore your settings back to the original format. Than try again. Now, you need to check/highlight the extra swap drives and click "Delete". This will mark those swap areas as free space. After you delete the 11 extras swap areas, click on the partition/drive you wish to add that space to. When the partition/drive is checked, click the "Change" button (Not Delete this time!). This will bring you to another dialog box which enables one to change the partition. Re-size the partition to account for the extra space you freed up in the deleting of all those swap areas (note: you need to add the numbers up yourself, freed space + current partition space) and click "Ok". Now you have added that swap area space to one of your usable partitions. (Note: you generally want to mount the partition in "/"). Also, as a rule, I generally only guess at how much free space to add to the partition. E.g. If I have 342332 Kb of free space, I will add 332000 to my partition. That will leave about 10 Gb or 10332 Kb of free space left. (Swap is used when you run out of memory). Than all you have to do is "Change" the remaining free space to a swap area. Just makes the math easier, that's all.  Also, the average person will never use more than 10 Gb of swap. I couldn't imagine how many applications you would need open to run out out all your memory plus 10 Gb of swap.